# How to change figure size in python Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

i'm working with `plotly.graph_objects` to generate a 3D plot.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,1,10)

fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(width=1000, height=400))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=np.sin(t), y=np.cos(t), z=t,
                    mode='markers', marker=dict(size=2, color='blue'), name='Base'))
```

and the result is reported in the following image:
[image: Result]

I would like the actual plot to be resized to 1000x400, not just the image with a small plot in the middle of it. Does anybody know how I can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Try this: `camera = dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=0.1));fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=400, scene_camera=camera, margin=dict(r=20, b=10, l=10, t=10))`

Comment: Nope, doesnt work

Comment: Try stopping the layout setup on the first graph object and adding new code (commented). `fig = go.Figure()`

Comment: No, sorry, still not working for me

Comment: I will share the code on which my comments are based, and I will expand it to Colab so you can check it out. Please check [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17kK_Yh5Cq5cmvGywFzgP9l_CFPXFO6l1?usp=sharing) and comment so that you can check it out. Upon confirmation, I will disable this link.